# .htaccess redirection

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect from this links using .htaccess

from
http://example.com/en/calligraphy-name/Elei
to
http://example.com/en/gallery?&search=Elei

Comment: Answer: by using a `RewriteRule` as offerd by the http server rewrite module. Have you tried that?

Comment: Please note that you are expected to try yourself to solve your issue. Only if you get stuck on the way, _then_ is the time to ask here and provide the code you are currently working with.

Comment: Can you explain why you would even consider using the opposite preferred method? You are turning SEO friendly URL's back to what webmasters, users and search engines do not like or want.

Comment: yes you are right Norcal, but it's not my decision

Comment: @BasharGh I understand. Some things we just have to do for those who ask of it. I did offer an answer based on the exact urls in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /en/calligraphy-name/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/gallery?&search=%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gallery.php [NC,L]
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try it if not work comment...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^calligraphy-name/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)$ gallery.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I do like your answer and I was not sure if the OP wants a method just for the URL mentioned, so I offered a method with a 301 redirect so all credits are given to the mentioned page and it causes search engines and bookmarks etc to update.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact example given and to update search engines and bookmarks etc..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^calligraphy-name/Elei(.*)$ /gallery?&search=Elei [R=301,NC,L]
```